# Añadir dependencias JPA HIBERNATE java

Tags: java

tengo las siguientes dependencias en mi proyecto . ¿La version de maven debería ir dentro de otro apartado? ¿O es correcta su actual localización?

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si desea utilizar JPA con Hibernate, solo necesita una sola dependencia de Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Esta dependencia extraerá todos los demás artefactos necesarios como dependencias transitivas (como la API de JPA, Hibernate Core y muchos otros).

Este es el poder de Maven. No es necesario que agregue nada manualmente al classpath ni que descubra qué archivos jar debe agregar. Una dependencia de Maven declarará como dependencias transitivas todo lo que necesita.